# Question about "put not your"

Tags: phrases, ambiguity, modifiers

An exercise asked me to rearrange the sentence "Put your money not in trust" such that there is no ambiguity to its meaning. At first glance I thought that "Put not your trust in money" sounded right, but thinking it over I realized that "not" is a squinting modifier here.

> (Put not) your trust in money -- Don't put your trust in money.
>   or
>   Put (not your trust) in money -- Put someone else's trust in money.

I looked up "Put not your" and found that it is used by Oliver Wendell Holmes in

> *Put not your* trust in money, but put your money in trust.

and in Psalms 146.

> *Put not your* trust in princes, nor in the son of man, in whom there is no help.

These quotes make me feel unsure of my reasoning, so I'm not sure what the correct answer ought to be.

Comment: This is archaic English. It's therefore not surprising you're unsure of your reasoning about it. In Modern English one would use _Do_-Support: _Don't put your trust in money._ That sentence is (a) grammatical; (b) colloquial; (c) unambiguous; and (d) true.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Note that *put not your trust...* is a dated/literary usage which would normally be expressed today by ***don't** put your trust...*

Comment: @JohnLawler: *Don't put your trust in money* doesn't have the form of a true statement.  It may be good advice but it is neither true nor false any more than *Don't trust your cat* is true (or false).

Comment: I spoke too unphilosophically. It's good advice, but of course, as an imperative, it can't be true; merely felicitous.

Comment: Your reasoning is sound. The awkwardness of squinting _not_ to ‘not your trust’ with no context to force it there makes the ambiguity slight; but it is there. You'd have to put the negated imperative last to avoid this altogether, though with Yoda-speak end up you would: “In money your trust put not”. What an elegant, natural, but most important unambiguous sentence!

Answer (score 1):

I believe for most readers the standard meaning is "(Put not) your trust", equivalent to "Don't put your trust", but you may get the other one by stressing "your", writing "Put not *your* trust in money", "Don't put *your* trust in money".

Answer (score -1):

It probably goes against the rules, but my instinct tells me that 'Put not your trust in money' carries the first meaning (Put not) your trust...

Certainly, in German grammar that would also be the case. Irrelevant here but maybe interesting.

I just wonder what meaning the sentence should have when it's rearranged though. Clearly, it is ambiguous as it is. So the task of rearranging has to choose a final meaning from the options.